# <input type="text"..../> doesn't read SPACES

Tags: php, mysql

So, I've been doing some update queries and I have successfully update the records in the database but my textfield doesn't seem to read the spaces from my database. For example my product_name is Meepo Plush. It only reads the 'Meepo' without the Plush. Why is that?

```
$servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "d2plushie";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble pasting the code using ctrl+k, can I send a file?

Comment: There is not the code that fails in your post. There is only the db connection

Comment: Make your question more clear and provide your code where you face difficulties

Comment: yes, I am trying but when I put the full code, it doesn't look good unlike that connection part. I have updated it with images for the other parts of the code. I will do my best to edit and paste the code correctly.

Comment: Where the code fails? On `UPDATE`?

Comment: @fusion3k the code doesn't fail at updating the record right through the database but in my page itself, it doesn't change the field when I update a string with spaces in it.

Comment: like this, https://imgur.com/gZDrmPH

Comment: So, i think it fails at UPDATE, since you get data directly from database. You have checked before if the update is ok? Where is the exact name of the product that has problem? (not 'hello world', i suppose...)

Comment: It doesn't fail at UPDATE, it just fails to update the text that is on the text field when I put a text with a space in it. The database is updated correctly. here -> https://imgur.com/fTXj9p5
but when I refresh the page, it goes back to the previous text even though it already changed in the database. Like this ->
https://imgur.com/gILbYr4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem reside on your HTML code, not in the PHP.
In HTML, attributes come in name/value pairs like: name="value".

This is correct:

```
<td><input type="text" name="product_name" value="Hello World"></td>
```

This not:

```
<td><input type=text name=product_name value=Hello World></td>
```

Our code output HTML as this second example, so the browser try to fix and the value is "Hello", not "Hello World".

You have to fix your code in this way:

```
'<td><input type="text" name="product_name" value="'.$row['product_name'].'"></td>'
```

even in the `<input name=price` part.

**Also please note:**
If you have a product with apostrophe in the name, your SQL query will fails. Take a look at [mySQL Prepared statements](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

Comment: Yes, after I realized that the problem was in the textfield, I was searching and found out that this was the problem. Thank you very much sir. Sorry, but I am still unable to give vote. :)

Comment: Thanks you very much. I will take note of that.